# How to prevent DOMXPath from expanding HTML entities?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, html-entities

I'm using DOMDocument and DOMXPath in PHP to find elements in an HTML document. 
This document contains HTML entities like &nbsp ; and I would like these entities to be preserved in the XPath output.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<html><head></head><body>&nbsp;Test</body></html>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//body');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent;
}
```

This code produces the following output (UTF-8):

```
[space]Test
```

But I would like to have this:

```
&nbsp;Test
```

Maybe it has something to do with LibXML that PHP uses internally, but I couldn't find any function that preserves the HTML entities.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: `[space]` is not UTF-8. Are you sure that it is U+0020 and not U+00A0?

Comment: @Alohci: Yes, you are right, it's U+00A0. I just wanted to make clear, that the output is displayed with whitespace instead of the nbsp entity.

Comment: @Dimitre: Sorry, but this is an XPath specific question. It's about the output of an XPath query.

Comment: I don't know but with SimpleXML you do **$xml = html_entity_decode($xml, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');** (http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php#107137)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPath always sees a representation of the XML document in which entity references have been expanded. The only way to prevent this is to preprocess the XML document, replacing the entity references by something that won't be expanded, for example changing `&nbsp;` to `§nbsp;`.

Answer (score 2):

An XPath processor isn't aware if a non-braking space character was specified as `&nbsp;` or as `&#xA0;' -- the character is always provided to it as a character entity --` `.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. An XPath processor doesn't operate on the Infoset, it operates on the XPath data model (XDM), which is defined in terms of the Infoset. The Infoset allows for the presence of Unexpanded Entity Reference Information Items. XDM does not. So it is indeed an XPath issue.